# Como faço para chamar uma função pressando Enter num <input>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu estou criando um *chat* para um site e preciso com que o usuário apenas aperte o `enter` e a mensagem apareça no *chat*, esse função funciona normalmente com um campo `textarea` mas com `input` não.

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post" id="frm-msg">
    <fieldset>
        <label> 
            <input type="text" name="mensagem" id="mensagem" class="textarea" />
        </label> 
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
     //inserir
     $("#submit").click(function() {
         var msg = $("#mensagem").val();
         msg = $.trim(msg);
         if (msg != '') {
             $.post('chat.php', {
                 mensagem: msg,
                 acao: 'inserir'
             }, function(retorno) {
                 $("#painel").prepend(retorno);
                 $("#mensagem").val('');
             });
         }
     });
     //atualizar
     setInterval(function() {
         $.post('chat.php', {
             acao: 'atualizar'
         }, function(retorno) {
             $("#painel").html(retorno);
         });
     }, 5000);
     $(document).keypress(function handleEnter(e, func) {
         if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13) {
             var msg = $("#mensagem").val();
             msg = $.trim(msg);
             if (msg != '') {
                 $.post('chat.php', {
                     mensagem: msg,
                     acao: 'inserir'
                 }, function(retorno) {
                     $("#painel").prepend(retorno);
                     $("#mensagem").val('');
                 });
             }
         }
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 5):

Creio que algo assim:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(event) {

    if(event.keyCode === 13) {

        // Sua função aqui

    }

});
```

Answer (score 4):

Javascript nativo:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode !== 13) return;
    // Aqui seu código
}):
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode !== 13) return;
    // Aqui seu código
}):
```

Você pode substituir `document` pelo elemento do seu campo, usando nativo o `querySelector('#idDoElemento')` ou no `jQuery $('#idDoElemento')`

Salve a condição que o foco deve estar no elemento ou em um filho dele.

Answer (score 3):

Carregar no `Enter` dentro de um input faz submeter/enviar a `form`, enquanto que na `textarea` cria uma nova linha.

Assim a resposta à sua pergunta passa por o que eu referí em cima e também por código que "escute" o teclado e procure quando a tecla `Enter` (que tem o codigo `13`) for carregada. Uma vez que o seu input tem uma ID você pode usar assim:

```
$('#mensagem').on('keydown', function(event) { // também pode usar keyup
    if(event.keyCode === 13) {
        // Correr código
    }
});
```

Dado o primeiro problema referido, têm duas opções:

**#1 Retirar o elemento `<input>` de dentro da form.**
[**Exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VPJMt/)

**#2 impedir o envio da `form`:**

Uma alternativa é impedir directamente no HTML

`<form onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">`

[**Exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VPJMt/1/)

Outra é sem ter javascript no html, adicionando isto no seu JavaScript:

```
$('#frm-msg').on('submit', function(){
    return false;
});
```

[**Exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VPJMt/2/)

Answer (score 0):

usando JQuery é bem simples

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="meuInput" />
```

Javascript

```
$('#meuInput').keydown(function(e){
 if (e.which == 13){
   chamaFuncao() // executa o que vc precisar
 }
})
```